# SQL Where clause: Use the greatest value between to columns in clause

Tags: sql, max, where-clause

I have a table with Column A and Column B. I am trying to select all the rows where the max value for each row between Column A and B is greater than 10

```
   A    B
   20   30
   5    9
   1    50

   Select A, B
   from table
   where max(a,b) > 10

   Desired Output:
   A    B
   20   30
   1    50
```

The above code doesn't work, how can I adjust the where clause?

Comment: `SELECT A, B FROM table WHERE A > 10 OR B > 10;` ??

Answer (score 1):

How/why are you using the word "max" in your question, when this question only regards 1 row per time?

```
select A, B
from table
where abs(a-b) > 10
```

Credit to Zak for tha abs function I weren't aware

Comment: You could also use the absolute value to avoid having 2 WHERE conditions: `WHERE abs(a-b) > 10`

Comment: ABS(A-B) gives the absolute value. If I had a row with 11 for A and 9 for B, the row would not be selected. I need to select each row where either A or B is greater than 10. The A > 10 OR B > 10 works but I am trying to find a way to use the  max value between 2 column/row values

Comment: So the other answer works, cool, select it. But when you say "the max value between 2 column/row values", this isnt clear to me. Provide another example that shows this case.

Comment: Sorry if it isn't clear. As an example, if for a specific row, you have column A equal to 11 and column B equal to 6, I would only like to use the value 11 to be compared in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an iif on the where clause:

```
  Select A, B
  from table
  where A > 10 OR B > 10
```

Edit: misunderstand the question!

Comment: He is not asking for that, else the desired output would not include the 1,50 row